# Saving .mp3 file to server using URL

Tags: php, curl

I have a URL `(http://somedomain.com/download.php?id=someid)` which when clicked and opened in browser, downloads a `.mp3` file. Now what I want to achieve is to make a curl request to this URL using PHP and save the `.mp3` on the server.

I want to keep the album art and name of the file as it is when downloaded using the URL directly.

So far I have come up with:

```
$downloadLink = downloadSong($allSongsSaavn[0]);
$ch = curl_init($downloadLink);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
if ($status == 200) {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/audio.mp3', $output);
}
```

But this is not doing anything. Not saving any file to the server.

Also, can anyone give me the idea about keeping the album art intact in the file saved to the server.

Comment: How are executing the script?....also what do you mean by `not doing anything`?

Comment: @Hackerman By `not doing anything` I mean that it is not saving file and not giving any error as well.. Currently I am executing this script in browser but I want to set it up as a cron.

Comment: Search about display errors con PHP...that's the first step.

Comment: @Hackerman That error display code is already there.. Even then nothing is printing in the browser. Nothing on apache logs as well!

Comment: is the dir you're trying to put the file into chmod 777?

Comment: @ManuelOtto he can really test this you know if he just try to create a file via FTP, or if he writes a simple script that creates a single file and check for errors and the file actually being created. Really you calling me a "wiseacres" because I suggest you stop giving wrong advises? What if he do that, set the directory permissions to 777, regardless if file permissions is the issue or not, and then forget about it, which is the most likely thing to happen? He can test the directory permissions with many other than your suggestion **SAFE** ways.

Comment: @void your code works just fine for me and it downloads the file to the server. Did try it in the same server though. If you have SSH access, you can try and download the file with `curl -O <url>` and see what you'll get.

Comment: Try running it from the command line `php -f thescriptname.php`

Comment: @ChristosLytras I agree, that's probably the best way to do it. I just tried to give advice based on what worked for me 90% of the time. But yeah, security wise it's not the smartest thing to do, forgot to mention that.